# Windows Workflow Foundation Switch Activity having Expression in Case (not constant)

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to implement the following code in **Windows Workflow Foundation** using **Switch** Activity:

```
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) return;

        switch (true)
        {

            case true when (userInput.Contains("hey")):
                Console.WriteLine("Got hey");
                break;
            case  true when (userInput.Contains("what") && userInput.Contains("man")):
                Console.WriteLine("Got what man");
                break;
            case true when (userInput.Contains("you")):
                Console.WriteLine("Got you");
                break;
            case true when (userInput.Contains("hey") && userInput.Contains("you")):
                Console.WriteLine("Got hey you");
                break;
        }
```

I am not able to get my head around this. If I choose **boolean expression** for my Switch in Workflow, I only get **True/False in the Case option** i.e. I can't add any expression that evaluates to True or False as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I know **I can use Nested Ifs here to get the desired result but that's what I want to avoid.**

***What I have tried/ searched so far:***

- **ElseIf Activity** -> I guess this could have solved my problem but it's only present in **.NET 3 and 3.5** and I am on **.NET Framework 4.7**, so I don't see it in my designer as it is obsolete. Here's the reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.ifelseactivity(v=vs.90).aspx
- I read about State Machines too but My case is a sequential workflow and I want to keep it simple. I am not sure If State machines can be of any use.
- I have also gone through this link (as per this link it's not possible but the post is very old) - [Switch of string in Workflow Foundation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874152/switch-of-string-in-workflow-foundation-issue)

Lastly, I am using **C# 7** (that's why I was able to write the above Switch Code :) )

Kindly assist.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though your using C#7 I imagine the underlying code of the switch statement is not. The activity designer will be designed with a traditional switch case implementation in mind. If you want to implement this sort of modern usage, you may have to write your own custom activity.

Comment: Yeah!! @DotNetHitMan Looks like I have to write my own custom activity. If this was inbuilt in WWF, it would have been great!